# How to perform integrals on an arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am new to arduino and I am trying to make a program that calculates the percentage of charge remaining in a battery, using the coulomb countig method (below a picture with the formula). Is it possible to perform this type of calculation from an arduino?

[image]

Comment: Cbat is constant during evaluation or function of t?

Comment: Yes, Cbat is constant

Comment: I thought for longer terms Cbat is in Coulomb and decreases with Integral I(t)*dt

Answer (score 0):

1.) The Model

Assuming CBat is the capacity of a battery and constant (physicist prefer letter Q for electrical charge; CBat may decrease with aging, "State of Health")

By Definition:

```
SOC(t) = Q(t)/CBat
```

Differential Equation:

```
dQ/dt = I(t)
```

Approximation: "dt=1"

```
Q(t)-Q(t-1) ~= I(t)
```

Or

```
SOC(t) ~= SOC(t-1) + I(t)/Cbat
```

2.) Ardunio:
Following is a pure virtual script, online compiler would not serve.

```
// Assume current coming from serial port

const float C_per_Ah = 3600;

// signal adjustment
const float current_scale_A = 0.1; // Ampere per serial step
const int current_offset = 128; // Offset of serial value for I=0A


float CBat_Ah = 94;  /* Assumed Battery Capacity in Ah */
float Cbat_C = CBat_Ah * C_per_Ah; /* ... in Coulomb */

float SOC = 0.7; /* Initial State of Charge */

int incomingByte = current_offset; // for incoming serial data, initial 0 Ampere
float I = 0; /* current */

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}


// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() 
{
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second

  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
  }
  I = (incomingByte-current_offset) * current_scale_A;

  SOC = SOC + I/Cbat_C;
  Serial.print("New SOC: ");
  Serial.println(SOC, 4);
}
```